# How do I download a Wikispaces page?

Tags: download, webpage, httrack

I usually download web pages with HTTrack when I know that I'll need that page, and I'll have no internet connection. That's what I wanted to do with Wikispaces page too.

However, HTTrack just can't download it:

```
Warning:  File has moved from elte-ik-linalg.wikispaces.com/ to
https://session.wikispaces.com/1/auth/auth?authToken=0c4659f405444bb5ffd1e1284246a1a87
Info:  No data seems to have been transferred during this session! : restoring previous one!
```

How do I download a Wikispaces page, then?

Comment: You could try `wget`. It has a recursive function..

Comment: @sinni800 - Gives an error, cannot download the page. If anyone manages to configure wget properly, then go ahead, I'll accept that as an answer too. Of course.

Comment: What's your depth on HTTrack? You can also add in a rule to exclude session.wikispaces.com and it will avoid that domain regardless of depth.

Comment: @Shiki Huh? That's strange. It should at least download the page itself without the recursive switch... Just with a `wget url`

Answer (score 0):

Try this advice ([from from BeckyG at the HTTrack forum](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/27316/18108/index.html)):

> If you log into your WikiSpaces Wiki,
>   on the upper left-hand side of your WikiSpace click Manage Wiki.  If you are
>   an "organizer" of your Wiki, you should have an Export option if you scroll
>   down.  If you have the Export option, I think you can save the whole Wiki as a
>   ZIP file.  However, if you are not an organizer/owner of that Wiki, you can
>   still download the contents by clicking the Web Folders (WebDAV) link.  It
>   should show a web address something like this:
>   YourWikiName.wikispaces.com/space/dav and the last two words in that link are
>   very imporant.  Using WinHTTrack Website Copier, start a new project.  On the
>   Add URL option, paste in your whole WikiSpaces address with /space/dav at the
>   end.  Type your WikiSpaces user name in the Login field (NOT your email
>   address associated with the Wiki... only your User Name will work) and type in
>   your WikiSpaces password in the Password field.  Click Next and Finish.  Your
>   WikiSpaces site should begin downloading.  It won't be "pretty" with images,
>   but it will provide all the files and documents (the text content) of the
>   Wiki.

I just tried this method myself. It took a moment or two, but it worked and was straightforward.

Comment: I'll try to ask an "organizer" to send me the wiki. I have tried the webDAV one, registered an account to try it out. After entering the URL and the user/pass combo, HTTrack started downloading. However, the log is full of errors (404), and in the end, the content is garbled, got tons of directories, and I just can't find anything. (The character encoding is also wrong.) **It's not usable, sadly.**

Comment: So you do not see the Export option? (It would be at the very bottom of the list if you have it).

Comment: I tried the webDAV option, since I'm just a member, I just registered for this. To download the Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I have another method, which I had *just* [posted on the HTTrack forum](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/27933/18108/index.html). I'll rewrite it here:

Let's say you want to mirror **`http://sitename.wikispaces.com`**

1. Create an account on wikispaces. Let's assume the username is "`MyName`"
   and the password is "`MyPass`".
2. **VERY IMPORTANT :** You *MUST* login with the
   account!
3. Add a URL *with* the username and password. You should get something
   like this: **`http://MyName:MyPass@sitename.wikispaces.com/`**
4. Add another URL *without* the username and password, e.g.,
   **`http://sitename.wikispaces.com/`**
5. In the Rules for the project, add **`+session.wikispaces.com/*`** on the bottom line (or second line from the bottom if you use `--disable-security-limits`)
6. Exclude `*/space/*` also, to prevent HTTrack from downloading auxilliary information (and the WebDAV files)
7. Start the mirroring process. After approx. 5~15 minutes, stop it, and peruse the (partial) mirror in the hard disk. Add sections you *don't* want to mirror into the Rules as exclusions.
8. Restart mirroring.

Hope this helps.

***Edit:*** The first time you start mirroring on Step 7, you *might* encounter the same error you experienced now. Just restart the mirroring, and all should go well.